# SQL Oracle, next free number from numeric column data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with an numeric column. There are data records,  lets take for Example { 1,7, 10, 11, 12, 19, 20}. I want to use SQL to get the next "free" number from a specific x:

```
>8 for x=7  
>8 for x=8  
>13 for x=10  
>21 for x=20
```

Does anybody have an idea?

OK: I want to insert something with an 'x'. The column is unique, so I cannot put something with x=7 in the table when there already is a '7' in there. So I want a routine that returns me '8' if there is already a record with '7'. Or '9' if there already is an '8'.

IN Pseudo SQL:

```
   x = 7 // for example
    select COL from myTable where COL= (x or if x does not exist, the y : y > x, y - x smallest possible)
```

Comment: I have no idea what the logic here is.

Comment: What do you mean by "free".  Your example makes no sense.

Comment: lol OldProgrammer  , I thought i was the only one lost here

Comment: OK: I want to insert something with an 'x'. The column is unique, so I cannot put something with x=7 in the table when there already is a '7' in there. So I want a routine that returns me '8' if there is already on record with '7'. Or '9' if there already is an '8'.

Comment: INSERT INTO table_name (Column_name ) VALUES ('1212');

Comment: What conditions , do you want to apply

Comment: Why not just use an Oracle sequence, and not worry about any of this?

Comment: Something like "AUTO_INCREMENT "

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3bf9b/9)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE NUMBERS
    ("NUM" int)
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO NUMBERS ("NUM")
         VALUES (1)
    INTO NUMBERS ("NUM")
         VALUES (7)
    INTO NUMBERS ("NUM")
         VALUES (10)
    INTO NUMBERS ("NUM")
         VALUES (11)
    INTO NUMBERS ("NUM")
         VALUES (12)
    INTO NUMBERS ("NUM")
         VALUES (19)
    INTO NUMBERS ("NUM")
         VALUES (20)
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select min(n.VAL) as NextFree
from (
   SELECT LEVEL as VAL
   FROM DUAL
   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 100000
   ORDER BY LEVEL
) n
left outer join NUMBERS d on n.VAL = d.NUM
where d.NUM is null
    and n.VAL >= 10
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3bf9b/9/0)**:

```
| NEXTFREE |
|----------|
|       13 |
```

Comment: great solution, thanks a lot. Only one change I need to make: n.VAL >= 10 in the last line.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the answer above but there's no need for a left join:

```
select nvl(nextfree, 10) as nextfree from (
select max(d.NUM) + 1 as nextfree
from NUMBERS d
CONNECT BY PRIOR NUM + 1 = NUM
START WITH NUM = 10
)

| NEXTFREE |
|----------|
|       13 |
```